# "Undefined variable" Error on remapped key in nvim

Tags: neovim

In unaltered nvim, the `s` key substitutes one character (and `S` substitutes a line).

I'm trying to remap `s` to `k` and vice versa, so in `lua/user/mappings.lua` I've added the lines

```
...
  n = {
    ["s"] = { "v:count ? 'k' : 'gk'", expr = true, desc = "Move cursor up" },
    ["k"] = { "s", desc = "Delete character and substitute text"},
    ["K"] = { "S", desc = "Delete line and substitute text"},
    ...
...
```

Most of my remappings work as intended, but hitting the `k` key gives an unexpected error: `E121: Undefined variable: s`.

**Why is that?**

The `s` key works as intended, moving the cursor up, and the `K` key also works as intended, deleting the entire line and entering insert mode.